# Convert multiple ant mxmlc target into gradle using GradleFX plugin

Tags: flash, gradle, apache-flex, ant, gradlefx

I have a complex java and flash project using ANT. I converting the project to use gradle instead. Can someone please help in converting the below sample ant target.

```
<target name="compile-flash">

    <mxmlc file="./flash/src/com/test/Some1.as" output="${build.dir}/flash/Some1.swf" debug="${flash.debug}" fork="true" maxmemory="512m">
        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml" />
        <load-config filename="./flash/conf/config1.xml" />
    </mxmlc>

    <mxmlc file="./flash/src/com/test/editor/Some2.as" output="${build.dir}/flash/Some2.swf" debug="${flash.debug}" fork="true" maxmemory="512m">
        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml" />
        <load-config filename="./flash/conf/config2.xml" />
    </mxmlc>

    <mxmlc file="${build.dir}/flashtest/flexunitapplication.mxml" output="${build.dir}/flashtest/FlexUnitApplication.swf" debug="true" fork="true">
        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml" />
        <load-config filename="flash/test/flexunit-config.xml" />
        <compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" append="true">
            <include name="libs" />
        </compiler.library-path>
        <compiler.library-path dir="${test.lib.dir}" append="true">
            <include name="swc"/>
        </compiler.library-path>
        <compiler.library-path dir="flash" append="true">
            <include name="lib/test" />
            <include name="lib" />
            <include name="bin" />
        </compiler.library-path>
        <compiler.headless-server>true</compiler.headless-server>
        <static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>true</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>
        <compiler.verbose-stacktraces>true</compiler.verbose-stacktraces>
    </mxmlc>

    <compc output="${build.dir}/swc/client_api_release.swc" incremental="false" benchmark="false" static-link-runtime-shared-libraries="true" compiler.debug="false" debug="false" compiler.optimize="true" compiler.strict="true" compiler.verbose-stacktraces="false" target-player="11.1.0">
        <include-sources dir="${generated.actionscript.dir}" includes="**/*.as" />
        <compiler.include-libraries dir="${dependencies.lib.dir}/swc/" append="true">
            <include name="*.swc" />
            <exclude name="*debug*.swc" />
        </compiler.include-libraries>
        <external-library-path file="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/framework.swc" append="true"/>
    </compc>
</target>
```

I know this is not in convention. But I can't change the structure bcoz it is a very old project. And I can't have different modules for different SWF or SWC.

**Can someone help me achieving the same result using gradleFX gradle plugin**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely want to make usage of Gradle's `UP-TO_DATE` checks so you'll want to set the `TaskInputs` and `TaskOutputs` for each task. It would likely look something like

```
apply plugin: 'base'

task compileFlash {}

task mxmlc1 {
    inputs.file 'flash/src/com/test/Some1.as'
    inputs.file '${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml'
    inputs.file 'flash/conf/config1.xml'
    outputs.file "${build.dir}/flash/Some1.swf"
    doLast {
        ant.mxmlc(
            file:"flash/src/com/test/Some1.as", 
            output:"${build.dir}/flash/Some1.swf",
            debug="${flash.debug}",
            fork="true",
            maxmemory="512m"
        ) {
            'load-config'(filename:"${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml")
            'load-config'(filename:"./flash/conf/config1.xml")
        }
    }
}

task mxmlc2 { ... }
task mxmlc3 { ... }

compileFlash.dependsOn [mxmlc1, mxmlc2, mxmlc3, ...]

compile.dependsOn compileFlash
```

This would probably start to get verbose so you might make a custom task so you could do something like

```
task mxmlc1(type:Mxmlx) {
    file = '"./flash/conf/config1.xml'
    loadConfig "${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"
    loadConfig "/flash/conf/config1.xml"
    // etc etc
}
```

Perhaps someone has even written a gradle plugin to do this for you?

Comment: Yes, there is a plugin GradleFx (https://github.com/GradleFx/GradleFx)  for this. But in their examples (https://github.com/GradleFx/GradleFx-Examples), they suggest having different modules for different swf. Thats why I can't figure out how to have multiple Mxmlc in one project.

Comment: Well, if you don't like that plugin it would be simple enough to write your own gradle tasks which wrap the flex ant tasks. Or you could just call ant inline as I've demonstrated